# Why was this question about new features in .NET 4.5 deleted?

Tags: discussion, specific-question, deleted-questions

I am trying to understand what specifically was wrong with the [now-deleted question on new features in .NET 4.5](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7425515/net-4-5-features).

It was claimed that it won't help someone in the future. What does this mean exactly? Why would this question not help someone in the future?

Comment: Where did you ask it?

Comment: @slhck - I'd guess this one? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7425515/net-4-5-features

Comment: Fear not, the wiki police have collected all you need http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/.NET_Framework_version_history#.NET_Framework_4.5_.28Upcoming.29

Answer (score 12, accepted):

I haven't seen the question, but some thoughts based on a hypothetical question about "new features in .NET 4.5".

- It *can* be answered. However …
- Who would want to find out what's *new* about .NET 4.5 as soon as a newer version is out?
- Asking for just a list of features is not really a good fit for SE. One feature per answer? Or even in an answer that lists all new features, don't you think this list might be quite long?
- If on Stack Overflow: Unless you're facing a concrete programming problem, how is such an answer – listing a gazillion of features – going to be useful?
- Can't this be answered more authoritatively by Microsoft? For example in [this //build/ presentation](https://web.archive.org/web/20210926171917/https://channel9.msdn.com/Events/BUILD/BUILD2011/TOOL-834T), or this [MSDN blog entry](https://web.archive.org/web/20160712215920/http://blogs.msdn.com:80/b/pfxteam/archive/2011/09/17/10212961.aspx), and finally, [this one here](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/whitepapers/whats-new-in-aspnet-45-and-visual-studio-2012).

Comment: That's pretty much what I thought with the addition that if the question I linked to is indeed the correct one there was some *very* localised language which will look extremely old within a year or so, e.g. "the upcoming .NET 4.5" and "preview release will soon be made available". The question could have been phrased better to avoid that, but it would still have fundamentally been a "list of X" question that only Microsoft can answer authoritatively prior to release without speculation.

Comment: I still often look up what was new in version 1.1, 2, 3, 3.5 and 4, just because I'm that type of sad person that sometimes discusses the history of .NET with other sad people. The phrasing could have been fixed - did it *really* need closing *and deleting*?

Comment: Also, there are [lots](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/292265/new-cool-features-of-c-sharp-4-0) [of](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/137688/c-sharp-3-new-feature-posts-and-not-about-net-3-5-features) [unclosed](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2879596/features-added-in-net-4-0) [questions](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1157256/new-features-in-silverlight-3) [on](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5873303/what-are-the-new-features-of-ado-net-2-0) [new](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2610861) [features](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/237041) on SO, of varying quality.

Comment: @romkyns I can't speak for those who have deleted it. I'd probably say, close the other ones you mentioned as well

Comment: Notice though that with the exception of the first question all of those questions have the highest rated answer as just a collection of links. That to me speaks volumes about the quality of the questions.

Comment: @romkyns: What are you talking about?  All those questions are closed as too localized.

Comment: @Won'tಠ_ಠ Yes, they are now, thanks to me linking to them :)